# How to subclass MPMoviePlayer controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am not sure if I understand what subclass of 'MoviePlayerController' means.
a) Is this when create new view controller and add MPMoviePlayerController instance in it?
b) Something else? Some code example would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This couldn't be a comment above as it takes up too many characters.

Okay @1110 I'm going to assume you want to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the player view, don't forget it already supports pinch gestures for full screen / removing full screen.
The code below is assuming you're working with a view controller with MPMoviePlayerController as an iVar.

You probably don't want to detect a single tap because it already uses tap detection count of 1 in order to show/hide the players controller.

Below is a code example for you with a gesture recognizer for a double tap

Code for PlayerViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface PlayerViewController : UIViewController {}

//iVar
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

// methods
- (void)didDetectDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap;
@end
```

Code for PlayerViewController.m

```
#import "PlayerViewController.h"

@implementation PlayerViewController
@synthesize player;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [player release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // initialize an instance of MPMoviePlayerController and set it to the iVar
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://path/to/video.whatever"]];
    // the frame is the size of the video on the view
    mp.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
    self.player = mp;
    [mp release];
    [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];

    // add tap gesture recognizer to the player.view property
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didDetectDoubleTap:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.player.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];

    // tell the movie to play
    [self.player play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didDetectDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    // do whatever you want to do here
    NSLog(@"double tap detected");
}

@end
```

FYI, I've checked this code out and it works.

Comment: Thanks I made something similar but it works :) 'working with a view controller with MPMoviePlayerController as an iVar', this is the real answer to my question because I didn't understand when someone says 'subclass mpmovieplayer' what it really means, inherit or view with iVar. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not sure what subclassing means, you should research the topic "inheritance". There should be a lot of material covering the subject for iOS specifically, when you create any file in Xcode, most likely you're already subclassing a class. Most of the time you'll be subclassing NSObject or UIViewController when creating a view etc.

You probably don't want to subclass MPMoviePlayerController as it's quite an advanced class built for streaming. MPMoviePlayerViewController works like a normal view controller only it already comes with a MPMoviePlayerController as an iVar.

condensed declaration below:

```
@interface MPMoviePlayerViewController : UIViewController {}
@property(nonatomic, readonly) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
@end
```

You can find some sample code in the Apple documentation center here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3-SW1

Movie player Xcode project you'll find here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798

Playing movies from an iOS device is really easy, make sure you read it all up on Apple's documentation. Checking out the header files for those classes will also give you more of an insight into what you're dealing with.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to use MPMoviePlayerViewController and everything works fine except I need to detect tap and double tap on player with some custom method handlers. So basically if I make UIViewController class with 'MPMoviePlayerController' instance in it that is subclassing, right?

Comment: @till please don't waste your time on stupid questions. What is simple for you might be nightmare for someone else, and if you don't wan't to help stay away.